# Maven output with displaying plugin+goal+project for each line as prefix

Tags: maven-2, logging, configuration

I really start to be fed up with my not knowing exactly what is happening inside a Maven build. Can I add extra info to console log like MDC in log4j? I want to see the followings for each line:

- plugin coordinate/goal
- project name/id/something

Do you know how to do this? Is there a log configuration somewhere? I expect something like this:

dependendency:resolve myproject - [INFO] bablajsgkfdjgkldsfjglkdf

dependendency:resolve myproject - [INFO] bablajsgasdfsadfsadfsakfdjgkldsfjglkdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible.

Comment: The funny thing in it, that I dont think I am the first, who would like it.